# Project Architecture using message queues

Tags: rabbitmq, distributed-system

I'm writing a project which uses RabbitMQ for message passing. It has a producer that generate tasks at scheduled time and put them into RabbitMQ queue. Also I have a pool of workers that get tasks from there, process them and put them into another queue (exchange). I need to store results into database. So the question is should I use the same app (scheduler) that generate tasks or write separate one for this task? This is slightly simplified version of what I do but can you tell me some cons and pros for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use separate app. Since it will be two simple apps that are totally decoupled.